# Why do I have 2 same keys with different values while debugging ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 same keys `labels` while debugging ES6 code in chrome but with one value as an object and the other as a string. Is it because of incorrect destructuring while debugging?

[image]

**EDIT:** Just to give more idea, this happens only while destructuring for labels

Comment: Maybe, some invisible characters in the key. Can you add the relevant code here.

Comment: Can you recreate that in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Yep, give us some code, to help you inspect that.

Comment: Maybe it's just a bug in your debugger. What's the value of the property when you access it from the javascript?

Comment: ^ What Bergi said. This happens a lot with large minified + sourcemapped files in my experience.

Comment: @Bergi I am using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116. Even I suspect its because of  the Scope watcher in Chrome which might be causing this. Just want to confirm if I am the only one or others are getting this issue as well

Comment: @AdityaSingh If you could post the code that you are using we could tell you if we're able to reproduce it. Currently we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @Bergi Can't share live code. :) But let me try to reproduce it in a Bin or fiddle